# find all tr in a table element with xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, element, children

```
def parse_header(table):
    ths = table.xpath('//tr/th')
    if not ths:
        ths = table.xpath('//tr[1]/td') # here is the problem, this will find tr[1]/td in all html file insted of this table

    # bala bala something elese

doc = html.fromstring(html_string)
table = doc.xpath("//div[@id='divGridData']/div[2]/table")[0]
parse_header(table)
```

I want to find all `tr[1]/td` in my table, but `table.xpath("//tr[1]/td")` still find all in html file. How can I find in just this element instead of all html file?

---

EDIT:

```
    content = '''

<root>
    <table id="table-one">
        <tr>
            <td>content from table 1</td>
        <tr>
        <table>
             <tr>
                 <!-- this is content I do not want to get -->
                <td>content from embeded table</td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</root>'''

root = etree.fromstring(content)
table_one = root.xpath('table[@id="table-one"]')
all_td_elements = table_one.xpath('//td') # so this give me too much!!!
```

now I do not want the embeded table content, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the elements that are sub-elements of your context node, prepend the period `.` operator to your XPath. So, I think the XPath you are looking for is:

```
.//tr[1]/td
```

This will select `td` elements that are sub-elements of the current table, not in the entire HTML file.

As an example:

```
from lxml import etree

content = '''

<root>
    <table id="table-one">
        <tr>
            <td>content from table 1</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table-two">
        <tr>
            <td>content from table 2</td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</root>'''

root = etree.fromstring(content)
table_one = root.xpath('table[@id="table-one"]')

# this will select all td elements in the entire XML document (so two elements)
all_td_elements = table_one.xpath('//td') 

# this will just select the single sub-element because of the period
just_sub_td_elements = table_one.xpath('.//td')
```

Comment: I have another question, I have update my question, how can I ignore the embeded table?

Comment: I do not want to get `content from embeded table` with `table_one.xpath('//td')`

Comment: OK - well in that case your XPath needs to be more specific - something like: `table_one.xpath('table[@id="table-one"]/tr/td')`

Comment: maybe the example is too simple,  but in my situation I think `table.xpath('./tr/td|./tbody/tr/td')` is better

Comment: I dont think `all_td_elements = table_one.xpath('//td') ` will select all TD ..the context  table_one sub dom ...